# Difference Between MD4 and MD5 encryption

Tags: c#, encryption

During coding, I have used both MD4 and MD5 encryption techniques. But there hasn't been any noticeable security difference between either of them. And yet, most of them prefer MD5, in fact specify it.
MD5 :

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] TDESKey = null;

TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes("CXPUB001"));  // ASYNC PRIVATE KEY CODE FOR DATA ENCRYPTION

//DATA ENCRYPTION 
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey; //SENDER KEY APPENDED
TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes(Message);
```

So, what is the difference, security wise, between using MD4 and MD5 ?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How do you test 'no noticable security difference"?

Comment: difrence between MD4 and MD5 is that MD5 has "more difrent" results if you take a lot of similiar strings of worse (only 1 char difrence) you could say that MD5 provides more difrent results then MD4

Comment: Encryption wise, both are 128 bits output size, both have 64bit length, decryption requires a key for both and it's hardly tough to decrypt the encryption offline.

Comment: Please note that it is not a good idea to learn cryptography by taking random samples from the internet. The above code is absolutely not providing enough security and would be considered broken by anybody studying crypto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both MD4 & MD5 are not encryption, they are a hash function that produce a 128-bit hash value. If you need encryption, use a proper encryption technology like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)

And to add on to the "security" aspect of MD5, it has been declared as non usable due to several vulnerabilities that can result in [hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack), and worst still, reversing the ciphertext back to their original values using rainbow tables. If you need hashing, use [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)

Comment: Rainbow tables are attacks on unsalted hash values. To use passwords for encryption (or password verification) you should use a (salted) PBKDF such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt. The security of the hash value has nothing to do with rainbow tables, and a hash function is therefore not broken if you can build a rainbow table. If you need **password hashing**, use a PBKDF.

Comment: @owlstead good point on rainbow tables on unsalted hashes, which is in this case. My answer actually aims to explain the difference between hash & encryption, as well as emphasizing that md4 & md5 are obsolete for security, another worthy mention: md5 hashes are still widely used as a file checksum

Answer (score 1):

MD5 was designed in 1991 to be a secure replacement. (Weaknesses were indeed later found in MD4 by Hans Dobbertin

The security of MD4 has been severely compromised. The first full collision attack against MD4 was published in 1995 and several newer attacks have been published since then. As of 2007, an attack can generate collisions in less than 2 MD4 hash operations.

The following are the differences between MD4 and MD5:

1. A fourth round has been added.
2. Each step now has a unique additive constant.
3. The function g in round 2 was changed from (XY v XZ v YZ) to (XZ v Y
       not(Z)) to make g less symmetric.
4. Each step now adds in the result of the previous step. This promotes
       a faster "avalanche effect".
5. The order in which input words are accessed in rounds 2 and 3 is
       changed, to make these patterns less like each other.
6. The shift amounts in each round have been approximately optimized,
       to yield a faster "avalanche effect." The shifts in different rounds
       are distinct.

Comment: You cannot give that answer without mentioning the security pitfalls that result of using MD5. I would say that there is a big similarity: both are broken.